# Stock issues/receipts for finished goods in SAP

Tags: sap

I am performing some material movement analysis (via MC.A) and have a quick question of interpretation: if I am looking at a finished material, is it accurate to say that a stock receipt represents completed production moving into stock and a stock issue represents either a shipment to a customer or a shipment outside of the home plant?

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed that yes, the information provided via the MC.A transaction reflects movements related to production order fulfillment and issues for customer sales orders and inter-company purchase orders.